# Using inner_hits inside aggregation script in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `products` index with a `categories` nested field that contains all categories the product is assigned to, plus their ascendants.

I need to write a query that returns the top products for a given list of category ids and group those products by their parent category.

Since a product can be in 2 or more categories, I need to show the product grouped only under the categories that matched the search query.

This is what I got so far:

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "categories",
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "categories.id": [1,2,3]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "category_group": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "...return the category to group by, depending on the matched nested category..."
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_products": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

The problem I hit is that the terms aggregation that builds the grouping category buckets needs to know which nested category matched the search query. It looks like that information is available in the `inner_hits` array in the results, but I need it within the terms aggregation script field.

**So, I guess my question is - is that possible at all? Or is there any other way to get the desired result?**

P.S: There is further complication that some categories cannot be used for grouping, and in such case, their parent category should be used, but this is something I can handle in the script.